# Queue of node using template

Tags: c++, pointers, templates, queue

I want to create a Queue of Node using template, for the purpose of displaying a BST tree in level order.
I create an abstract class `Queue` a derived of this class called `QueueVector`, and I have my `tree` file.
I don't understand why when I create a queue of node the code doesn't compile and say `did not override any base class methods`
, but if for example I change node to int, it works perfect.

This is the line:
`Queue<Node>* q = new QueueVector<Node>;`
What I have to do so I can create queue of node

Queue pure virtual class

```
#pragma once
template <class T>
class Queue
{
public:
    virtual void clear() = 0;
    virtual void enqueue(int value) = 0;
    virtual int dequeue() = 0;
    virtual int front() = 0;
    virtual bool isEmpty() const = 0;
};
```

Queue Vector

```
template <class T>
class QueueVector : public Queue<T>
{
public:
    // constructor requires a starting size
    QueueVector(int max = 100);
    //QueueVector(const QueueVector&);

    // implement Queue protocol
    void clear() override;
    T dequeue() override;
    void enqueue(T value) override;
    T front() override;
    bool isEmpty() const override;
private:
    T* data;
    int capacity;
    int nextSlot;
    int firstUse;
};
```

Tree

```
template <class T>
class Tree
{
protected:
    //--------------------------------------------------------
    //  inner class Node
    //      a single Node from a binary tree
    //--------------------------------------------------------
    class Node
    {
    public:
        Node* left;
        Node* right;
        T value;
        Node(T val)
            : value(val), left(nullptr), right(nullptr) {}
        Node(T val, Node* l, Node* r)
            : value(val), left(l), right(r) {}
    };      //end of Node class

    Node* root;

public:
    Tree() { root = nullptr; }   // initialize tree
    bool isEmpty() const;
    void level() {  _level(root); } ;

private:
    void _level(Node* current);


template<class T>
inline void Tree<T>::_level(Node* current)
{
    Queue<Node>* q = new QueueVector<Node>;
    if (root == nullptr)
        return;
    q->enqueue(root);
    while (!q->isEmpty())
    {
        root = q->dequeue();//I can do this only if I store node
        if (root->left != nullptr)
            q->enqueue(root->left);
        if (root->right != nullptr)
            q->enqueue(root->right);
    }
}
```

Comment: Where is your main and the impl part of `QueueVector ` function? It much better to provide a compilable code here.

Comment: @prehistoricpenguin The main do nothing that cause problem. The only thing I want is that I can create in my function queue of node using template

Answer (score 0):

> code doesn't compile and say did not override any base class methods , but if for example I change node to int, it works perfect.

You can't override a pure virtual method *and* change its signature.

This is your base class's `enqueue` method:

```cpp
    virtual void enqueue(int value) = 0;
```

While this is your derived class's:

```cpp
    void enqueue(T value) override;
```

Because you marked the derived method `override` (a good thing!), the compiler tries to find `void Vector::enqueue(T value)` and can't because it doesn't exist, unless `T` is `int`

Since your base class is a template anyway, `Vector::enqueue` and `Vector::dequeue` should use `T` as well instead of `int`